# Not Booting past Logo

Tags: boot, kubuntu

I have been messing around with uninstalling a program (emacs24) on Kubuntu 14.04 and for this followed [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377245/how-to-completely-remove-my-emacs) instruction:
 (see Hartmut's answer).

After I didn't manage to get rid of all emacs files, I gave up and moved onto creating a shortcut to launch the konsole via
`System Settings > Gestures and Shortcuts`.
This initially worked fine until at some point whenever I hit the shortcut, firefox would start up, with a new tab of Google search results for 'konsole' (????). 
I figured a restart may resolve the issue but when wanting to shut down, all that happened was the display dimming ever so slightly. When no other programs would start either. Upon crashing the system, I can not get past the pulsating Kubuntu logo.
I tried using boot-repair from the live usb that the original image was on, which said it was succesfull, but didn't change anything. Am unsure at what stage I might have mucked something up (hence the gory detail, sorry!).
Any suggestions what I might do to fix it? I was hoping to avoid a completely fresh install of Kubuntu.